# Windows Authentication on Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, active-directory

I am building a .net mvc web app on Azure. Currently my client asked for login to the application with their user accounts which they login to the windows.
I've searched couple of solutions but none of them works for me.

Azure AD needs to synchronize accounts. We don't want this.
AD FS needs to be installed on the server as far as i know it's also sycnhronizing.

Is there any method to login on-premises active directory users to Azure App without ADFS stuff and any synchronizing process?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you were developing an web app and deploy it to Azure.

> Is there any method to login on-premises active directory users to Azure App without ADFS stuff and any synchronizing process?

I don't thinks it is possible. Since the Azure and on-premises are two different environment.

A easy way is using the [Azure AD connect](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-aadconnect/) which doesn't require to install the ADFS. And there is an **Password synchronization** option in its Express settings which will sync the account from on-premises to cloud with password. Then you can protect your web app with Azure AD and it enable the users to sign-in with the accounts synced from on-premises or which created in the cloud.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. If i use Azure AD Connect, it'll sync all accounts in my clients domain to my Azure Account AD service. I don't want that actually. I guess there's no way to keep that accounts in a single web app users directory or something?

Comment: Either you will need to synchronize the accounts to use Azure AD as the STS or have an STS (e.g. ADFS) that is behind your on-premises AD to login the user. Those are you only 2 options. Currently ADFS will give you the desktop SSO that you client is asking. So, will other 3rd party STS providers as well. Or you are doing it the old fashioned way where you are hosting the app in Azure in a network that is extendeded to the clients on-premises network with DC's and using windows integrated authentication. Wouldn't recommend this.